# How to detect key press on Xamarin.Mac NSTexField?

Tags: xamarin.mac

I am trying to detect when a user presses enter while editing a single line NSTextField, so as to submit the data they've entered.

There doesn't appear to be any events on NSTextField which would be useful,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subclass NSTextField and override the keyUp method:

```
[Register("CustomTextField")]
private class CustomTextField : MonoMac.AppKit.NSTextField
{
    public CustomTextField(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void KeyUp (NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        if (theEvent.KeyCode == 36) {
            Console.WriteLine ("You pressed enter!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add that there should be an enumerator in `MonoMac.AppKit` that has more literal versions of these keys. i.e: `(int)NSKey.Return`.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work for this event, but couldn't find anything better, thanks.