# Use NSTextView in the background in an Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

How to use a NSTextView in the background of an Xamarin.Forms application and feed it with key events so that it behaves (input wise) like it was part of a window and is focused?
I already tried to create an instance and feed it all key events but this was not enough (didn't fire any event)

```cs
_textView = new NSTextView();

//...

public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
{
    NSEvent.AddLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDown, @event =>
    {
        _textView.KeyDown(@event);
        return @event;
    });
    NSEvent.AddLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyUp, @event =>
    {
        _textView.KeyUp(@event);
        return @event;
    });
    Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());
    base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);
}
```

Comment: Can you please have a try the code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969630/how-to-capture-key-down-events-at-application-level-in-xamarin-mac)? And also have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582967/how-to-detect-key-press-on-xamarin-mac-nstexfield) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

I created a `KeyHandlingContentView` derived from `ContentView` in Xamarin.Forms and a custom Renderer for Mac that implements `INSTextInputClient`.

This way the key events can be passed from that custom renderer to the Xamarin.Forms control.

Comment: Don't forget to mark accept this answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) which will help more people with same problem:).